# "Mastery Guidance" meaning

Tags: vocabulary

What does **Mastery Guidance** mean in this context?

> "Replace a vague idea of 'purpose' with a manageable and measurable objective that is made ahead of practice and gives **mastery guidance**" – Practice Perfect (book)

I think it means that it's going to give you a pathway to follow to achieve mastery. Am I right?

Or is it more like "giving you guidance that comes from a master"?

Comment: It's the same as "gives guidance to your mastery of ...", so "a pathway to achieve mastery". It is the same pattern as "give (indirect object) (direct object)" = "give DO to IO"

Comment: It looks like a garbled sentence, or possibly made-up jargon.

Comment: Off topic (lit crit/analysis). There are many reasons such questions are off topic, one being that divining an author's intentions is often impossible. Try contacting the author or publisher. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct in your interpretation.  The author is stating that by setting specific and objectively measurable goals for each practice session you can creat a concrete pathway of improvement and are more likely to achieve mastery than by having only vague goals or a "purpose".